# Gomobile toolchain out of date, only in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, go, gomobile

I am working with the latest gomobile, Go, and Android Studio builds.

When I run the gradle tasks from the terminal they work as expected and build the correct binaries, however from within Android Studio I receive an error:

```
bin/gomobile: toolchain out of date, run `gomobile init`
```

Of course I have re run gomobile init many times and no change. My assumption is that Android Studio is using some config that I can not identify.

I appreciate this is a somewhat edge case question, but if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be helpful.

TLDR; ./gradlew myproj:bind works fine in terminal, fails in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten to the bottom of this in case anyone else has the issue;

1. It appears, at least for me, the Gradle plugin wasn't respecting the location of the GO bin. Instead it looks up the gobin using;

   ```
           gobin, err := exec.LookPath("go")
   ```

I have a number of Go versions installed (for various reasons) so my forcing the gobin was failing. To discover this I have added debug logs to the `env.go` file. In general the logging on the file is not the most clear when attempting to debug.

Comment: Nice catch, and more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a gomobile error message, seen in [`cmd/gomobile/env.go#L69-L83`](https://github.com/xing/gomobile/blob/689a4dbed73dbaf25136ccda2ece3026acd2ac74/cmd/gomobile/env.go#L69-L83):

```
// Find gomobilepath.
gopath := goEnv("GOPATH")
for _, p := range filepath.SplitList(gopath) {
    gomobilepath = filepath.Join(p, "pkg", "gomobile")
    if _, err := os.Stat(gomobilepath); buildN || err == nil {
        break
    }
}

verpath := filepath.Join(gomobilepath, "version")
installedVersion, err := ioutil.ReadFile(verpath)
if !bytes.Equal(installedVersion, version) {
    return nil, errors.New("toolchain out of date, run `gomobile init`")
}
```

So double-check the value of `GOPATH` between your local session and your Android Studio session.
See for instance [this old (2015) thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/go-mobile/ZstjAiIFrWY) to see if any of those comments still apply.

Comment: Plus Go 1.8 might have fixed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17996, with https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/33372/2//COMMIT_MSG

Comment: Thanks both. The GOPATH *should* be extracted from the org.golang.mobile.bind plugin, in fact when I remove my GOPATH from my profile, the terminal function still works as it is extracted.

Comment: I believe that  change was focussed on correcting the incorrect example, not actual functionality. (i.e. The example does not have an "=")